# Invalid multibyte string error when loading a csv file in R

Tags: r

I am loading a csv file but unable to understand the error

R studio

```
data <- read.csv("IMDB_data.csv")

Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<96>'
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code of your current soluation and edit your question!

Answer (score -1):

To read a CSV file-

```
data <- read.csv("file_name.csv", header = True, sep = ";")
```

In this one liner-

header is a logical value for whether the first line contains the attrbutes

sep is the field separator character

For more details, refer-
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html